URL redirect in azure front door with query string
can we do the following URL Rewrite using azure front door? the requirement is to modify the last path /customer1 to a query string for the backend origin.
https://example.com/customer1 --> https://example.com/?customer=customer1
Thanks -Nen

you can use the URL Rewrite feature of Azure Front Door. You can use the custom forwarding path to copy the incoming path that matches the wildcard path to the forwarded path. In this case, you can use / as the custom forwarding path and /* as the match path. Then, you can add a rewrite rule to rewrite the URL path and URL query string only when the path contains /customer1.

URL rewrite (front-door-classic)


Azure Front Door supports URL rewrite by configuring a Custom forwarding path when configuring the forward routing type rule. To modify the last path /customer1 to a query string for the backend origin, you can use the URL Rewrite feature
In you front door, either edit the default one or add a new route

If editing the default one then select rule set in the left pane.
Select the routing rule you want to add URL rewrite to and fill in the required details for the route. Ensure the "Accepted protocols" are set to HTTP and HTTPS. Set the "Patterns to match" to /* and ensure preserve Unmatched Path is set to Yes to preserve any additional path segments after /customer1. Save it.

Done


References:

URL rewrite (front-door-classic)
Similar frondoor url rewrite thread
MS Doc1
MS Doc2

